# Shuffling a list with a constraint

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, random

Preparing a new psychophysical experiment,
I have 48 original stimuli displayed 4 times (4 conditions), resulting in 192 trials.
Trying to randomize the order of presentation during the experiment,
I need to maximize the distance between the 4 display of the same original stimuli.

Please consider :

```
Table[{j, i}, {j, Range[48]}, {i, Range[4]}]
```

Where j is the original stimuli number and i the condition

Output Sample :

```
 {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, 
  {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4},   
  ...
  {47, 1}, {47, 2}, {47, 3},{47, 4}, 
  {48, 1}, {48, 2}, {48, 3}, {48, 4}}
```

How could I shuffle the order of presentation of those 192 items, maximizing the distance between identical items with regard to j, the original stimuli number?

Comment: I have trouble following what you want... could you post a sample output?

Comment: @Yoda let`s say I am displaying 48 images 4 times resulting in 192 trials. I want to display the same images with the most different ones in-between. If I have only 3 images repeated 4 times. I guess it will be {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3} ? Well actually thank you, I think we can`t do better than this ? So for my case it would go like this : {Range[48],Range[48],Range[48],Range[48]} ?

Comment: While I'll not post a competing answer, let me introduce you to the terminology of what you're asking. What you want is to introduce some level of "correlation" into the distribution of samples. A perfectly randomized set would exhibit no correlation between the positions of the images, yet adding the constraint of maximal spacing does as you pointed out with your list `{1,2,3,1,2,3 ...}`. In a sense, this decreases the level of randomness (entropy) in the sample set by reducing the number of configurations allowed. For instance, there are only 3 configs available in your `{1,2,3}` list.

Comment: @rcollyer, Thank you for those clarifications !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to have a compromise between randomness and your constraint of maximum distance between original stimuli. A maximum distance is obtained when you arrange the stimuli in 4 identical series of 48 stimuli (a non-random presentation). The distance is fixed at 48 for every original stimulus in that case.

If you distribute the 192 pairs totally random the average distance between the original stimuli is 38.6 on average, with minimum and maximum possible distances of 1 and 144 respectively:

```
t = Flatten[Table[i, {4}, {i, 48}]]; 

{Mean[#], StandardDeviation[#]} &@  
Table[
  rs = RandomSample[t, 192];
    Mean[Mean[Differences[Flatten[Position[rs, #]]]] & /@ Range[48]] // 
   N, {10000}
]

(* ==> {38.60370417, 1.397151004} *)
```

You can do it differently. First split the 48 stimuli in 2 blocks of 24 (1-24 [block I] and 25-48 [block II]). Then generate random permutations (p) of I and II: p(I)p(II)p(I)p(II)p(I)p(II)p(I)p(II).

The average distance now becomes:

```
{Mean[#], StandardDeviation[#]} &@  
Table[
  rs = 
    Join[RandomSample[Range[24]], RandomSample[Range[25, 48]], 
         RandomSample[Range[24]], RandomSample[Range[25, 48]],
         RandomSample[Range[24]], RandomSample[Range[25, 48]], 
         RandomSample[Range[24]], RandomSample[Range[25, 48]]
    ];
  Mean[Mean[Differences[Flatten[Position[rs, #]]]] & /@ Range[48]] //N, {10000}]

(* ==> {48., 0.} *)
```

So we now have a much more random presentation while the average distance is still 48 (minimum distance now is 24 and maximum distance is 47). Note the standard deviation of 0. As an exercise  I'll leave the proof of why that must be so to you.

---

**Update 1**
I've arranged the stimuli in two groups here, 1-24 and 25-48. I suggest you use a new random initial arrangement for each subject, before you start breaking up into two groups. This will introduce a bit of extra balancing over subjects.

---

**Update 2**
And now, the code for the stimulus-condition combo generation:

First, randomize condition over all stimuli:

```
m = MapThread[
       List, 
       {
         Table[Range[48], {4}], 
         Table[RandomSample[{1, 2, 3, 4}], {48}]\[Transpose]
       }, 2
    ]
```

Then, break up in groups of 24, shuffle those, and arrange as one list:

```
Flatten[RandomSample /@ Partition[Flatten[m, 1], 24], 1]
```

To randomize the order for each subject (as I suggested above in update 1) a small change is necessary in the first part:

```
initialArrangement = RandomSample[Range[48]]; 
m = 
 MapThread[
    List, 
    {
       Table[initialArrangement, {4}], 
       Table[RandomSample[{1, 2, 3, 4}], {48}]\[Transpose]
    }, 2
 ]
```

Please note that it would be really wrong to put the first line (`RandomSample[Range[48]]`) inside the `Table`!

---

For Mr.Wizard here the infix notation version to show I'm really trying  ;-)

```
m~Set~MapThread[List, (Range[48]~Table~{4}~
    List~((RandomSample[{1, 2, 3, 4}]~Table~ {48})\[Transpose])), 2]
```

and the second part:

```
(RandomSample /@ m~Flatten~1~Partition~24)~Flatten~1
```

The variation of the first part, like above:

```
initialArrangement~Set~RandomSample[Range[48]]; 
m~Set~MapThread[List, (initialArrangement~Table~{4}~
    List~((RandomSample[{1, 2, 3, 4}]~Table~ {48})\[Transpose])), 2]
```

BTW Forget the parenthesis in the second part and the output, though looking similar, will be completely wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not really, I changed it to the simpler random permutation format. Thanks.

Comment: @mr.wizard That part seemed trivial to me, but I can add it. Have to get back to my PC first though (1 hr), so if you can add it instead it would be fine.

Comment: @Sjoerd Might still be too regular, since the second half never appear during the runs of the first half, and vice versa. Depends on how much the experimental subjects know or suspect, I guess.

Comment: @Daniel Quite often randomization and other order manipulations aren't done to outsmart your subjects (preventing them from guessing the correct' answer etc.), but to prevent transfer/order effects. Examples of these could be learning effects, adaptation (to light levels for instance), or getting tired and/or bored. So, randomization is less of a goal than a means to get rid of those effects. Several techniques have been developed for this goal, like grecco latin squares (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square).

Comment: @Daniel In this case 500 for some reason wants to maximally separate conditions, but also wants some randomization. I thought the solution above to be a good compromise, but I'm curious what you have in mind.

Comment: @Sjoerd Nothing exciting. I might go with four shuffles of 1-48. That way one does still risk seeing the same pain near to one another, but only as a pair, so at least two of each foursome are always well separated from two others.

Comment: @Sjoerd, I wish there was a Tag when answer are so detailed and expanded ! THank You very much !

Comment: @Mr.Wizard We have prolonged the discussion/joke way too long, but I'll be in the chat box for a couple of minutes

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
a = RandomSample@Range@48;
Flatten[Array[Partition[Riffle[a, #1], 2] &, 4], 1]
```

Comment: thank you, would you mind explaining the use of Riffle here ?

Comment: @500 The Riffle is used to add the iteration number {{_,1} ... {_,4}} for each sample, as per your request

Comment: Thank You, I feel like this one is gonna come in my vocabulary now :-)

Comment: This shuffles but I don't see how the constraint is imposed - or could be. Presumably there needs to be some kind of weighting scheme so if `{23,1}` is near the end of the 1's, `{23,2}` shouldn't be near the start of its group. But then in the limit each of the four rounds would have the same order. You would need to specify the in minimum acceptable distance between two appearances of the same image to avoid this.

Comment: @Verbeia I thought like you, but after reading 500's comment under his question I changed my mind.

Comment: @Verbeia and belisarius, thank you youu made me realize, I think, that I cannot get a random sample and the maximum distance given, I believe in my comment. Is that correct ? I would like to implement a a minimum acceptable distance. Shall I ask another question or Edit this one ? Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Following Belisarius' way I would rather write like this :

```
RandomSample[Flatten[Table[{j, i}, {j, Range[48]}, {i, Range[4]}], 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a sidebar on generating your original array.

This form is needlessly long:

```
Table[{j, i}, {j, Range[48]}, {i, Range[4]}]
```

You can write simply:

```
Table[{j, i}, {j, 48}, {i, 4}]
```

You could also use Array:

```
List ~Array~ {48, 4}
```

Or, if you want the sublists joined:

```
Tuples@Range@{48, 4}
```

Comment: Thank you very much : This : List ~Array~ {48, 4} is so elegant to me but I don`t get the way ~ works really. Could you explain when, when not we can use this syntax ?

Comment: @500 I shall try to.  Infix ( a ~function~ b) notation can be used when there exactly two arguments for a function, and both arguments are composed with greater binding power than infix notation itself.  Therefore we can write `17 ~Mod~ 5` in place of `Mod[17, 5]`, but we cannot write `10 + 7 ~Mod~ 5` because infix binds before `Plus` and therefore this reads `10 + (7 ~Mod~ 5)`.  See this page for more:  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html

Comment: Look Mamma, no hands: `i~List~j~Table~(i~List~48)~Table~(j~List~4)` :D

Comment: @mr.wizard belisarius provides a nice example of the reasons I don't like infix notation. Reading this is almost a mind game. And as you rightly notice above, you have to know the precedence table (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) by heart to successfully use it. Same holds for @ and /@ of course, but the less you have to remember the better it is.

Comment: @Sjoerd I actually do not find his highly contrived example that hard to read.  There is no ambiguity given the parentheses, and the fact that it is all ~infix~ notation.  You just read it left to right, alternating functions and arguments.  Further, as you note, any experienced *Mathematica* user must become familiar with the order of operations.  Nevertheless, I shall attempt to avoid ambiguity in the code I post, or at least add extra whitespace to help others visually parse it.

Comment: @Sjoerd I have no expectation that you will agree with me, but for reference, if I remove the explicit `List`s, I find this infix form: `{i, j} ~Table~ {i, 48} ~Table~ {j, 4}` more readable than this regular form: `Table[Table[{i, j}, {i, 48}], {j, 4}]`.  Add a few extra square brackets to each, and I favor the infix form even more strongly.

Comment: It's perhaps all about mental images. i~List~j doesn't map easily to {i,j} for me. `Join`, on the other hand, works fine in infix notation. It sticks between the operands, glueing them. That's an image that works. Your`Table` example doesn't have that.

Comment: I'm not a fine iPad typist, so if your willing to wait a bit I'll get back to you in half an hour

Comment: Discussing infix while ~ is three keyboards away ( as it is on the iPad) is no fun.